# Theory on loosely coupled viewmodel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

Can anyone please explain the theory on creating a loosely coupled viewmodel.

I have attached some example code below to try and explain what I mean.

I have 2 example classes just for this example

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Web.UI.Models
{
    public class EmployerAddress
    {
        public string address { get; set; }
        public string city { get; set; }
        public string region { get; set; }
        public string country { get; set; }
        public string postZipCode { get; set; }
    }

    public class EmployerDetails
    {
        public string position { get; set; }
        public string gender { get; set; }
        public string dob { get; set; }
    }

    public class DisplayEmployerAddress : IDisplayEmployerAddress
    {
        public IEnumerable<EmployerAddress> employerAddr()
        {
            List<EmployerAddress> Data = new List<EmployerAddress>();
            Data.Add(new EmployerAddress
            {
                address = "address1",
                city = "city1",
                region = "region1",
                country = "country1",
                postZipCode = "post zip1"
            });
            return Data;
        }
    }

    public class DisplayEmployerDetails : IDisplayEmployerDetails
    {
        public IEnumerable<EmployerDetails> employerDetails()
        {
            List<EmployerDetails> Data = new List<EmployerDetails>();
            Data.Add(new EmployerDetails
            {
                position = "trainee",
                gender = "male",
                dob = "22-08-1964"
            });
            Data.Add(new EmployerDetails
            {
                position = "trainee2",
                gender = "male2",
                dob = "22-08-1970"
            });
            return Data;
        }
    }
}
```

The code above has the interfaces:

```
IEnumerable<EmployerAddress> employerAddr();
IEnumerable<EmployerDetails> employerDetails();
```

I then use Ninject to bind the above.

```
kernel.Bind<IDisplayEmployerAddress>().To<DisplayEmployerAddress>().InSingletonScope();
kernel.Bind<IDisplayEmployerDetails>().To<DisplayEmployerDetails>().InSingletonScope();
```

At this point everything is OK, I could just change DisplayEmployerAddress etc and so long as all the methods etc match up the code will still work.

I then create a viewmodel

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Web.UI.Models
{
    public class EmployerDetailsViewModel
    {
        public string age { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<EmployerAddress> EmployerAddress { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<EmployerDetails> EmployerDetails { get; set; }
    }
}
```

But now this would cause a problem as EmployerAddress is now tightly coupled, so if I change the code, it will now have to be updated in 2 places.

In my controller I have

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IDisplayEmployerAddress _address;
        private readonly IDisplayEmployerDetails _details;

        public HomeController(IDisplayEmployerAddress address,
                              IDisplayEmployerDetails details)
        {
            _address = address;
            _details = details;
        }
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Title = "Title";
            var Address = _address.employerAddr();
            var Details = _details.employerDetails().AsEnumerable();
            var Age = _details.employerDetails().FirstOrDefault().dob;
            var employerModel = new EmployerDetailsViewModel
            {
                EmployerAddress = Address,
                EmployerDetails = Details,
                age = age.calAge(Age)
            };
            return View(employerModel);
        }
```

I keep the controller lightweight as all the books I read say keep as little code as possible in the controller, so to calculate age I use a static class.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Web.UI.Models
{
    public static class age
    {
        public static string calAge(string dob)
        {
            //Would cal age here
            return "48";

        }
    }
}
```

So my question is 3 parts.

1. Is this example the correct way.
2. As my viewmodel is now tightly coupled, how do I make it loosley
   coupled.
3. If I did not want to use a foreach loop how can I get each item out
   of say EmployerDetails

   This employer holds the position of @Model.EmployerDetails.position the gender is @Model.EmployerDetails.gender

   ```
   <ul>
   @foreach (var d in Model.EmployerAddress)
   {
      <li>@d.address</li>
       <li>@d.city</li>
       <li>@d.country</li>
       <li>@d.region</li>
       <li>@d.postZipCode</li> 
   }
       </ul>

   <ul>
   @foreach (var dd in Model.EmployerDetails)
   {
      <li>@dd.position</li>
       <li>@dd.gender</li>
       <li>@dd.dob</li>
   }
       </ul>
   ```

So far

This employer holds the position of @Model.EmployerDetails.position the gender is @Model.EmployerDetails.gender

Worked out question 3, changed code to **@Model.EmployerDetails.FirstOrDefault().position**

Hope the above example makes sense on what I'm trying to learn

Thanks

George

Comment: As you have `EmployerDetails` and `EmployerAddress`, does there also exist an `Employer` class, where those other two classes can belong to? As no reference between those two types of data exists they shouldn't be coupled at all.

Comment: Hi ebeeb, the code is just an example of how i'm trying to explain viewmodels as i see it

Comment: I adjust the code to a more fitting implemetation for the MVVM pattern and get back to you.

Comment: I have a hard time understanding your question. In particular I do not understand _"But now this would cause a problem as EmployerAddress is now tightly coupled, so if I change the code, it will now have to be updated in 2 places."_ Tightly coupling requires at least two 'things' to be coupled but you only mention one 'thing'. Also, what "2 places" are you referring to?

Comment: @Martin Liversage Hi What I mean is the dal is referenced in 2 places kernel.Bind<IDisplayEmployerAddress>().To<DisplayEmployerAddress>().InSingletonScope(); (Ninject) and public IEnumerable<EmployerAddress> EmployerAddress { get; set; } (viewmodel). If I now change EmployerAddress to say EmployerAddressNew I would need to change EmployerAddress in Ninject and viewmodel. I was just wondering if it was possible to change code so that I only needed to change it in ninject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Employer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class EmployerAddress
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Region { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string PostZipCode { get; set; }

    public int EmployerId { get; set; }
}

public class EmployerDetails
{
    public string Position { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string Dob { get; set; }

    public int EmployerId { get; set; }
}

public class MyRepository : IMyRepository
{
    public IEnumerable<Employer> GetEmployers()
    {
        return new List<Employer>
            {
                new Employer {Id = 1},
                new Employer {Id = 2}
            };
    }

    public IEnumerable<EmployerAddress> GetEmployeeAddresses()
    {
        return new List<EmployerAddress>
            {
                new EmployerAddress
                    {
                        EmployerId = 1,
                        Address = "address1",
                        City = "city1",
                        Region = "region1",
                        Country = "country1",
                        PostZipCode = "post zip1"
                    },
                new EmployerAddress
                    {
                        EmployerId = 2,
                        Address = "address2",
                        City = "city2",
                        Region = "region2",
                        Country = "country2",
                        PostZipCode = "post zip2"
                    }
            };
    }

    public IEnumerable<EmployerDetails> GetEmployeeDetails()
    {
        return new List<EmployerDetails>
            {
                new EmployerDetails
                    {
                        EmployerId = 1,
                        Position = "trainee",
                        Gender = "male",
                        Dob = "22-08-1964"
                    },
                new EmployerDetails
                    {
                        EmployerId = 2,
                        Position = "trainee2",
                        Gender = "male2",
                        Dob = "22-08-1970"
                    }
            };
    }
}

public class EmployerChangedEvent
{
    public EmployerChangedEvent(Employer selectedEmployer)
    {
        Employer = selectedEmployer;
    }

    public Employer Employer { get; set; }
}

public class EmployerViewModel
{
    private readonly IEventAggregator _events;
    private Employer _selectedEmployer;

    // Configure Ninject properly to get those types
    public EmployerViewModel(IEventAggregator events, IMyRepository myRepository)
    {
        _events = events;
        Employers = myRepository.GetEmployers().ToList();
        EmployerAddressViewModel = new EmployerAddressViewModel(_events, myRepository);
        EmployerDetailsViewModel = new EmployerDetailsViewModel(_events, myRepository);
    }

    public List<Employer> Employers { get; set; }

    public EmployerAddressViewModel EmployerAddressViewModel { get; set; }
    public EmployerDetailsViewModel EmployerDetailsViewModel { get; set; }

    public Employer SelectedEmployer
    {
        get { return _selectedEmployer; }
        set
        {
            _selectedEmployer = value;
            // this notifies the dependent view models in a loosley coupled way
            _events.Publish(new EmployerChangedEvent(_selectedEmployer));
        }
    }
}

public class EmployerAddressViewModel :
    IHandle<EmployerChangedEvent> // specifies which events shall be caught
{
    private readonly IMyRepository _myRepository;
    private Employer _selectedEmployer;

    public EmployerAddressViewModel(IEventAggregator events, IMyRepository myRepository)
    {
        _myRepository = myRepository;
        // this subscribes this view model to the passed event aggregator
        // from your main view model (EmployerViewModel)
        events.Subscribe(this);
    }

    public EmployerAddress EmployerAddress { get; set; }

    public void Handle(EmployerChangedEvent message)
    {
        _selectedEmployer = message.Employer;
        EmployerAddress = _myRepository.GetEmployeeAddresses()
                                       .FirstOrDefault(e => e.EmployerId == _selectedEmployer.Id);
    }
}

public class EmployerDetailsViewModel :
    IHandle<EmployerChangedEvent> // specifies which events shall be caught
{
    private readonly IMyRepository _myRepository;
    private Employer _selectedEmployer;

    public EmployerDetailsViewModel(IEventAggregator events, IMyRepository myRepository)
    {
        _myRepository = myRepository;
        // this subscribes this view model to the passed event aggregator
        // from your main view model (EmployerViewModel)
        events.Subscribe(this);
    }

    public EmployerDetails EmployerDetails { get; set; }

    public void Handle(EmployerChangedEvent message)
    {
        _selectedEmployer = message.Employer;
        EmployerDetails = _myRepository.GetEmployeeDetails()
                                       .FirstOrDefault(e => e.EmployerId == _selectedEmployer.Id);
    }
}

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // do this with Ninject
        var employerViewModel = new EmployerViewModel(new EventAggregator(), new MyRepository());

        // this selection should actually be user input
        employerViewModel.SelectedEmployer = employerViewModel.Employers.First();

        // select another one
        employerViewModel.SelectedEmployer = employerViewModel.Employers.Last();
    }
}
```

As I am not familiar with ASP.NET, my answer doesn't imply any of UI notifications.

I suggest Caliburn.Micro's [event aggregator](http://caliburn.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=The%20Event%20Aggregator) class here, because it solves your coupling problem nicely. This library is worth a look anyway for learning the MVVM pattern.

The `IEventAggregator` allows you to subscribe with instance of a class to an instance of the aggregator. If multiple view models share an instance of the event aggregator you can easily send events from one to another in a loosley coupled way.

I refactored your original code, to make it more fitting for the actual MVVM pattern (*your first question*, let's say this implementaion is more proper). I've added an `Employer` class, which is basically the main object. It only has an id. The `EmployerDetails` and `EmployerAddress` also have a new property `EmployerId` which is a reference to the `Employer` they belong to.

I have put all the stuff to query data in the `MyRepository` class!

For each of those three classes exist three **seperate** view models and they're only coupled through the event aggregator they share (*answers your 2nd question*). The `EmployerViewModel` manages the main data objects of type `Employer` and publishes an event as soon as the selected `Employer` changes. The new value is passed into the `EmployerChangedEvent` which then is caught by the view models which handle this certain kind of event (`IHandle<EmployerChangedEvent`). In their `Handle()` implementation the passed employer is put into a private field of the receiving view model.

This is just a console application which simulates user input, though try with putting break points on both of the handle methods, as the `SelectedEmployer` changes.

I think some kind of stuff I do in my `Main()` method should be done in your controllers. I have to mention that this code is just for showing the benefits of the MVVM pattern, it might be over abstracted in some cases. Also things like querying the repository efficiently are not covered at all!

I think my answer also solves your 3rd question, as I see no `foreach` is anymore needed.

Remember to reference `Caliburn.Micro` if you'd like to run this code. Just get it through NuGet or download it [here](http://caliburn.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Thanks ebeeb, will start digesting all you wrote and try and learn from it. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Get back if you need some more help.

Comment: The question is about MVC (ASP.NET MVC) but this answer relates to MVVM (XAML). These patterns are different and for instance using the event aggregator from Caliburn Micro in an ASP.NET MVC project does not make much sense. It almost seems like the question is in French but the answer is in German.

Comment: @Martin Liversage: I agree that I messed up with MVVM and MVC. So it's rather not good to use Caliburn.Micro in an MVC project, though its implementation of the `IEventAggregator`. I think using the [event aggregator pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventAggregator.html) does not conflict with the MVC design, does it?

Comment: @ebeeb: The view models used in ASP.NET MVC only lives during the request-response cycle so there are no other "live" view models to send events to.

Comment: @MartinLiversage: What about [SPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application)'s? I experimented with the [Hot Towel MVC 4 WebApi](http://www.johnpapa.net/hottowel/) template. It uses [Durandal](http://durandaljs.com/), which basically **is** Caliburn.Micro for MVC. Is it not possible to build SPA's with ASP.NET? If not, my answer seems really to be wrong. :)

Comment: @ebeeb: Surely you can build SPA's in ASP.NET MVC but there is no live object graph on the server side. Instead each HTTP request creates a view model that is serialized and sent to the client. On the client side you could probably benefit from using an event aggregator.

Comment: @ebeeb tried using code in my mvc app, could not get it to work, but I notice above that this has already been discussed. So my question is how would I loosely couple the viewmodel

Comment: @MartinLiversage tried using code in my mvc app, could not get it to work, but I notice above that this has already been discussed. So my question is how would I loosely couple the viewmodel